# Backend Delete button, doest parse the cid[] array that contains the id of checked, checkboxes

Tags: joomla-2.5, component, development, mvc, form-fields-types

In the admin section of a component, i have this form:

[image]

I just added the checkboxes in the left following this [Joomla API](https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_Backend_Actions).

**MyCode:**

```
$i=$rows_num;
$checked    = JHTML::_( 'grid.id', $i, $voter["vid"] );
echo $checked;
```

And the Delete button shown in picture like that:

```
$bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'delete', 'Διαγραφή συγκεκριμένων ψήφων', 'index.php?option=com_exnetpolls&deleteit='.$isnotempty.'&gotcha=yo ');
```

The component isnt mine and the creator didnt use a controller ( every single action is executed in exnetpolls.php file  ) so i created a new file getitdeleted.php and  in exnetpolls.php i added this code :

**exnetpolls.php (first file that getting executed)**

```
if($_GET['deleteit']!="" && $_GET['deleteit']!=NULL){ 
    include("getitdeleted.php");
}
```

**And in getitdeleted.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
echo "test";
$cid = JRequest::getVar('cid',array(),'','array');
var_dump($cid);
if(isset($_GET['gotcha'])){
echo "worked".$_GET['deleteit'];
//code to delete from db
unset($_GET['gotcha']);
}
```

I know the way im using is a bit retarted,but it works except that the:

```
$cid = JRequest::getVar('cid',array(),'','array');
var_dump($cid);

returns array(0) {}
```

Altough if i type in my browser :

```
index.php?option=com_exnetpolls&deleteit=18&gotcha=yo&cid[]=2

the var_dump returns : array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }
```

I also noticed that i could somehow parse the value with jquery using the id of input, but i would like to do that if it was my last option.

```
<input id="cb15" name="cid[]" value="2278" onclick="Joomla.isChecked(this.checked);" title="Πλαίσιο ελέγχου για τη σειρά 16" type="checkbox">
```

I tried also to pass the cid[] somehow with the delete button like so:

```
$bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'delete', 'Διαγραφή συγκεκριμένων ψήφων', 'index.php?option=com_exnetpolls&deleteit='.$isnotempty.'&gotcha=yo&cid[] ');
```

But it doesnt work.Could a joomla specialist enlight me please on what am i doing wrong here ?

EDIT: forgot to mention that i would like to check before pressing the DELETE button if `cid[]==NULL` so i can change the value of `$isnotempty` . when i var_dump the  `$cid = JRequest::getVar('cid',array(),'','array');` in the file that i create the input, i get again a null array.

Comment: Do your checkboxes have correct markup? It should be something like  `<input id="cb0" name="cid[]" value="73" onclick="Joomla.isChecked(this.checked);" type="checkbox">`

Comment: I allready mention it in the post ;) 
`<input id="cb15" name="cid[]" value="2278" onclick="Joomla.isChecked(this.checked);" title="Πλαίσιο ελέγχου για τη σειρά 16" type="checkbox">`

Comment: Ah sorry missed it. Try to var_dump($_POST) just after echo "test". Is it containing cid array or it is also missing?

Comment: Seems it is missing : `var_dump($_POST)-> array(0) { } `

Comment: Wait , wait because i dont use a method="POST" somewhere. Should i ? My form is like that:`<form action="" name="adminForm">` and i use the delete button to do the work. Should i put METHOD="POST" to my form, and make the delete button a submit button that would do the same stuff??

Comment: Just gave you the same answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comments I would suggest that your delete button invokes only GET action. That means all input fields are not processed. Try to use normal `<form>` with `action="post"` like:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_exnetpolls&deleteit='.$isnotempty.'&gotcha=yo'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
```

Comment: POST:array(3) { ["cid"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "2273" } 
I think im gonna cry of joy. After 8 hours im redeemed! You are a lifesaver dude , thank you very much !

Comment: A quick mini question, how could i check with this way if a checkbox is checked or not ?!

Comment: You should have `<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />` in your form and this value will be not zero when checkbox is checked. It is updated by `onclick="Joomla.isChecked(this.checked);"` function.